# Why is my IIS7 server asking for credentials when the directory is named "reports"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

It does not seem to matter how I have the site configured the error still occurs. For example:  `test.com/test.html` will come back with whatever text I have.

If I put that html into a directory "reports" (`test.com/reports/index.html`) the website will ask for credentials. If the directory is changed to any other word (e.g. `test.com/report/index.html`) or `test.com/reportss/index.html` it works.

I am guessing that there is a config file somewhere that Is causing the issue, I have just run out of places to look.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server, or SQL Reporting services, installed on this server?

Comment: I have a sql server running as the database server, but it is on a different box.

Comment: I apologize.  I do have SQL running on the box.  The same code works on a box that does not have SQL on it.  AGAIN to be clear with my mistake, the server I am having the issue with, DOES run SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server Reporting Services will use the Virtual Directory `/Reports` by default.  You can configure SSRS to use a different Virtual Directory, a seperate web site or remove SSRS all together.

See the Technet [Deploying Reporting Services and Internet Information Services Side-by-Side](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630449.aspx) for more information

Comment: I was able to fix this with the reporting services configuration tool.